# AutoMapper - map a property without a `set;` implementation

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there some way to map a `IList<>` property which does not have a `set;` method?

Source Class:

```
public class SourceClass
{
    private IList<string> strings;

    public IList<string> Strings { get { return this.strings; } }

    public SourceClass() { this.strings = new List<string>() { "s1", "s2", "s3" };
    //...
}
```

Destionation Class:

```
public class DestinationClass
{
    private IList<string> strings;

    public IList<string> Strings { get { return this.strings; } }

    public DestinationClass() { this.strings = new List<string>();
    //...
}
```

As you can see, neither class has `set;` implemented. The result is that when I perform `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(source, destination)`, the `Strings` property is empty.

The obvious solution is to provide a `set;` implementation is `DestinationClass`, however, I would like to know how to provide a custom configuration in order to deal with these troubles.

Currently, my configuration is:

```
public class XProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a constructor like this.

```
public class DestinationClass
{
    private IList<string> strings;

    public IList<string> Strings { get { return this.strings; } }

    public DestinationClass() : this(new List<string>()) { }

    public DestinationClass(IList<string> strs) {
        strings = strs.ToList(); // clone it
    }
    //...
}
```

Then you can make the mapping with the `ConstructUsing` method, to tell `AutoMapper` to call the constructor that you created.

```
public class XProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
            .ConstructUsing(x => new DestinationClass(x.Strings));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure AutoMapper to recognize non-public members.
Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#configuring-visibility)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with immutable object, i suggest to you pass it as  parameter to destination class, and it will be like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ConstructUsing(s => new DestinationClass(s.Strings))
```

And the `DestinationClass`:

```
public class DestinationClass
{
    private IList<string> strings;

    public IList<string> Strings { get { return this.strings; } }

    public DestinationClass(List<string> strings = null)
    { 
        this.strings = strings ?? new List<string>();
    }
   //...
}
```